# GlassFish 3.1.2.2 war can't find jar inside ear

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I have built an ear with this structure (not all files shown here):

```
myapp.ear/
    myapp-ejb.jar
    myapp-web.war
    META-INF/
        application.xml
    lib
        myapp-common.jar
```

The problem is, when code in the war tries to reference classes in myapp-common.jar, it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Note the contents of `META-INF/application.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">
  <display-name>pncr-portal-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myapp-web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>myapp-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>/lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

The library directory is defined here as being in the `/lib` directory relative to the root of the ear, which is exactly where it is, yet it is not loaded into the classpath despite the Java EE 5 (and presumably 6) spec saying that it should be loaded into the classpath.

Comment: Set the `myapp-common.jar` as `provided` only in the `war-pom` and let `myapp-common.jar` have default scope in the the `ejb-pom`. That works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was referencing a class in a slightly different package than the one I thought. The package no longer existed, yet Maven was compiling it without complaining. So I blew away my local repository and tried again. I still got the error. Then I found the problem: In myapp.taglib.xml, I am still referencing an old version of a class in myapp-common.jar that is now in a different package.

So the lesson is: If you see `ClassNotFoundException`, also look in your taglib.xml file(s).

Answer (score -1):

Verify that you have `META-INF/manifest.mf` in your war file, containing (something like):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/myapp-common.jar
```

Comment: It's not there. The problem is, I have to declare the dependency in Maven as `<scope>provided</scope>` in both the ejb-jar and the war otherwise there will be a jar both the ejb-jar and the war and quite possibly the ear as well. The maven-ear-plugin skips dependencies declared in this way with respect to the classpath in the manifest.

Comment: Actually, these Class-Path entries are not required. https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/packaging_libraries_with_ears