# ANT target to generate Manifest Class-Path for WAR to see jars in EAR's /lib directory

Tags: ant, jar, war, ear

I am deploying an **EAR** with a utility jar, say *A.jar* located in the EAR's **lib** folder. My EAR's **application.xml** is:

```
<application ...>
<library-directory>lib</library-directory>

<module><ejb>cashflow-ejb.jar</ejb></module>

<module>
    <web>
    <web-uri>cashflow-war.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>cashflow</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
</application>
```

However, my WAR can't see the classes in the **EAR**'s *lib/A.jar* and the deployment fails with a **ClassNotFound** exception. I went through these two similar posts: [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103724/glassfish-3-1-2-2-war-cant-find-jar-inside-ear) and [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330067/jboss-war-file-in-ear-cant-find-jar-library-on-classpath), but none of the solutions offered there seemed to work. Basically I think I need the **WAR**'s MANIFEST file to have a **Class-Path:** entry pointing to the **EAR's** lib. Can someone provide an **ANT** target for that? I've tried "**../lib**", as in:

```
<war
needxmlfile="false"
basedir="${webroot.dir}"
warfile="${build.dir}/${project.distname}.war">
<exclude name="WEB-INF/src/**"/>
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="../lib"/>
</manifest>
</war>
```

But it didn't seem to work and neither did "**lib/A.jar**", "**../lib/A.jar**" or "**/lib**" for the **Class-Path** value. The only solution that deploys in JBoss AS 7.1.1 is to copy *A.jar* both in the **EAR**'s */lib* location and in the **WAR**'s *WEB-INF/lib* but then I have two copies of the same **JAR** in my **EAR**.

Comment: Your WAR should be able to access all class files located inside JAR files placed in the EAR directory. Rather than play around with manifest files, I'd open a bug report with your JavaEE container provider and have them fix it or provide a workaround. Unless you didn't define your EAR as an EAR 5.0?

Comment: My application.xml's <application xmlns> tag specifies a version attribute of "5" and an xsi:schemaLocation attributes that points to an application_5.xsd file. My understanding is that that qualifies as a 5.0 EAR.

Comment: Ok. Then, there's either a bug in your JavaEE container, or another unrelated class loading problem. Try starting your container with the `-verbose:class` flag and see where things fail.